# Html, external CSS link fails on Linux

Tags: html, linux, lighttpd, filepath

I know similar questions have been asked but cannot see why our external css link doesn't work on Linux.  The folder structure on both Windows and Linux is:

```
/
    /static
        /css
            style.css
        /img
        /js
    /html
        index.html
```

The index.html links to style.css with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" />
```

It works on Windows but fails on Linux with a 404.  This would imply that the /static folder and sub-folders don't have the correct permission but they actually have identical permissions as the /html folder.  If all the /static content is placed in the /html folder then it works.

Has anyone come across a similar situation or know what the problem is?

Comment: Try to open that css file form browser

Comment: What happens if you remove the `..`? I'm not sure you really need that. Windows is usually more forgiving with file paths / names etc

Comment: @animatora Opening css file from browser returns a 404.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts the "../" provides for a relative path which is needed.  A '/' at the front would turn it into an absolute path.

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite ? It has to be a server config issue. Make sure it is configured right.

Comment: I understand the purpose of `../`, but why are you wanting to work with a relative path? With a  pathname like `/static/css/` it looks like the CSS files will always be referenced from there.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Tried with "../" and without '/' and the response for both methods is 404 . My head hurts too!

Comment: @animatora Problem was with the mod_rewrite regex. It works good now. Thanks!  Would accept your comment as the answer but not possible unless you re-answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using mod_rewrite ? It has to be a server config issue. Make sure it is configured right

Answer (score 0):

To be sure the path is ok, open index.html on the browser and check the path of css file from the page source there.

The problem can probably be permission on the css file.

The user apache ir running on must be able to read the file, otherwhise it will fail to load it

you can try running:

```
chmod a+r style.css
```

to add read permission to everyone on that file, or:

```
chown [user]:[group] style.css
```

to change the owner of the file to the user and group apache is using.

You can also check which user apache is running on in this question [Finding out what user Apache is running as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as)

By default it usually is apache user and apache group.

Comment: Opening index.html in browser returns a 404.  Using lighttpd, which points to /templates folder and executes index.html, but cannot access the css folder.  Checked relevant folder/file permissions and all are consistent.  Lighttpd by default doesn't care for specific user/group permission.